# JavaScript not running in IE at first run

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Having a rather strange issue within IE. When I launch IE and load a page (from a local domain, let's call it "http://amazing.dev/") the JavaScript on the site does not run.

I know what you are thinking, turn on JS you plonker (http://goo.gl/FnzoW). It's on and the reason I know it's on is that when I launch developer tools and reload the page, the JS runs.

There is a lot of JS within this site, so it could be anything. But there are no errors, no warnings, nothing. On reload, works perfectly!

Any ideas/experience of this would help massively! It could just be my machine!

Comment: Do you get any JS errors? Check the console. JS errors can break execution of _all_ code. Maybe there is a timing error, like relying on one file being executed before another.

Comment: Are there any console.log statements? IE does not expose a global console object with the dev tools closed.

Comment: No, As I said, no errors and with a reload of the page with the console open, everything works fine!

Comment: _with the console open_ Are you calling `console.log` perhaps? Older versions of IE will give an error if you try to `console.log` but the console isn't opened.

Comment: Check it's not doing console.log. This works if the console is open, but fails if it's closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem occurs only when you don't launch the developer tools, there is probably a call to `console.log` somewhere in your code. The console isn't available until you open those tools.

You can use this code (I'm not the author) to prevent the crash :

```
if (!window.console) {
    var names = ["log", "debug", "info", "warn", "error", "assert", "dir", "dirxml",
    "group", "groupEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "count", "trace", "profile", "profileEnd"];
    window.console = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
        window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
    }
};
```

Comment: I've seen this script before but never used it. Very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on IE there isn't a console object when the debugger is not open.
that's why with the debugger open everything works fine for you.

just add this to the beginning of the page and it will probably work.

```
if (typeof console == "undefined") {
    this.console = {log: function() {}};
}
```